# Blob-video link doesn't work in Chromium browser

Tags: javascript, html5-video, blob, chromium

I use URL.createObjectURL() to generate blob-url to local video.
It works on most of the browser (tested bunch of mobile and desktop browsers).
But now I tried to use Chromium (for autotesting purposes).
It does generate blob-url, but it is just empty.
So i can't put this url to video source. Obviously, video events like 'loadedmetadata' do not trigger.
Also, blob link doesn't work in another tab.

```
function setVideo(el) 
{
  console.log('inited');
    const file = el.files[0];
  let video = document.querySelector('#video');
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  let videoSrc = video.querySelector('source');
  videoSrc.src = url;
  videoSrc.setAttribute('type', file.type);
  let metaLoaded = function () {
   console.log('metaloaded');
  };
  
  video.load();

  if ( video.readyState > 0 )
    metaLoaded();
  else
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', metaLoaded, false);
}
```

Example https://jsfiddle.net/pwdhs42v/3/
Works on all browsers except of Chromium (122.0.6258.0)
Any idea why it works like that? Could it be some security restriction? If so, can I disable it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked chrome://media-internals, and got those errors:

**FFmpegDemuxer: skipping invalid or unsupported video track**

**FFmpegDemuxer: no supported streams**

**"Warning, FFmpegDemuxer failed to create a valid/supported video decoder configuration from muxed stream**

Chromium does not support the h264 codec out of the box, and ironically, all of my test videos were encoded in this format.

I should have checked this in here:
https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/

So, I have to use other video formats or build Chromium with h264 support.

Comment: You can try WebM video format for quick blob testing in Chromium, but yes in general, it would be better to have H.264 enabled (since it is the main codec for MP4 video files). I did not know H.264 isn't supported. I didn't know that one cannot play MP4 files in Chromium...